# Проблема jQuery UI dialog

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

Проблема: почему-то когда на странице есть скролинг и пользователь находится внизу страницы, то страница автоматически скролится вверх, а модальное окно при этом остается вверху. В чем может быть проблема?

Привожу фрагмент кода:

```
$("#dialog3").dialog({
position: ['center','center'],
autoOpen: false,
modal: false,
height: 160,
width: 400,
buttons: {...
```

Comment: Что за плагин?

Answer (score 2):

Проблема в вызове диалога. Надо делать привязку клика к кнопке не как показано на офф сайте, а через `$('#button').on('click', function () { /* ... */ });` или просто в коде кнопки на `onclick=""`

Answer (score 0):

Последняя библиотека?
Не работает во всех браузерах?

Так тоже не работает?

```
$( "#dialog3" ).dialog( "option", "position", 'center' );
```

А у #dialog3 у Тебя в стилях ничего криминального не прописано?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй поставить 
`modal: true` 
тогда у тебя при вызове диалога скрола нету, при закрытии есть.